# Missing OOTB support in Gradle for Maven's provided scope. Spring's Gradle propdeps-plugin not functioning as expected

Tags: plugins, gradle, multi-module

I have come across [Spring.io's plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin). Initially it seemed great.

I have defined the following in my *root* build.gradle file

```
allprojects  {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'

...

    configurations.provided.transitive = true
    configurations.provided.visible = true
}
```

I have one sub-module (lets call it `sub1`) that has the following definition:

```
dependencies {
    provided(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-core', version:'1.2.0') {
        exclude(module: 'slf4j-log4j12')
        exclude(module: 'log4j')
    }
...
}
```

And a second sub-module (lets call it `sub2`) that is dependent on the first such:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':sub1')

...
}
```

when I invoke the `clean build` tasks of `sub2` I get the following error:

> /.../.../.../blahblah.java:12: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf
>   does not exist import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

The missing import exists in the jar specified in the `provided` scope in the build file of `sub1`

I had thought that setting the following:

```
configurations.provided.transitive = true
configurations.provided.visible = true
```

would do the trick (Note: it doesn't work with any value to these props).

Is the plugin "broken" or am I using it wrong?

Comment: It seems that `provided` scope isn't accessible at the compile time. Maybe try `compile`?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to use compile since it would beat the point of marking the jars as provided (i.e. supplied by the framework, in this case hadoop...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `provided` dependency is a `compile` dependency that is *not* transitive. Hence it's no surprise that `sub1`'s `provided` dependency won't end up on `sub2`'s compile class path. To fix this, you'll need to declare the dependency both for `sub1` and `sub2` (e.g. by declaring it under `subprojects {}` in the root build script).

Comment: Thanks! 2 questions remain. The first is: Why then did declaring the `configurations.provided.transitive = true` not have the _expected_ effect? The second: declaring under `subprojects`, necessitates both projects to be within the same hierarchy, this is fine for a case in which the hierarchy is relatively small and thematically coupled. But what if I want to achieve the same result between two projects not declared together within the same `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: ad 1. `compile project(':sub1')` is shorthand for `compile project(path: ':sub1', configuration: 'archives')`, and sub2's `archives` configuration isn't linked to its `provided` configuration. This is to prevent `provided` dependencies from propagating, which is their whole point. ad 2. Declare the dependency in both projects.